# Finding out table view's section from collection view's data source methods

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, collectionview

I have a `UITableView` with 2 sections each of which contains one cell. These cells contain `UICollectionView`s. These collection views are of different types. Trying to follow the MVC design pattern, I make my `ViewController` a data source and a delegate of both `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`.

Here is the data source code of my table view:

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: recomendationCellId, for: indexPath) as! RecomendationsTableViewCell
        cell.collectionView.dataSource = self
        cell.collectionView.delegate = self
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: collectionCellId, for: indexPath) as! CollectionsTableViewCell
        cell.collectionView.dataSource = self
        cell.collectionView.delegate = self
        return cell
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Now, I need to dequeue cells for the collection view, by using `collectionView(_:,cellForItem:)` method. Inside of it I need to check the section of the table view  to dequeue the right cell.

The problem is that I know that it should have a simple solution but can't figure it out. Do you have any suggestions how this can be achieved?

Comment: You could subclass the collectionView and and add a property <tableSectionIndex:Int> and set it when you dequeue your tableViewCell

Answer (score 0):

If collection view is inside cell then handle it with in `cell` only...so when you are setting `cell.collectionView.dataSource = self` it means you are setting `delegate` to current view controller not the cell, means that collection view look for the data source in current view controller.

As you are using MVC its better to implement a datasource and delegate methods inside `cell`.

So you need to ultimately set `cell.collectionView.dataSource = cell` as `cell` will implement data source and delegate methods.

Comment: But shouldn't the data source (and/or delegate) be a view controller? I mean, view controller is the one that provides cells with data and reacts to different actions. Cells are just subclasses of a `UIView`. So, views shouldn't be responsible for providing data to cells.

Answer (score 0):

Your MVC pattern *won't break* even if you confirm to the collection view delegates and datasource methods from your cell itself!
A *model* is responsible to *provide you with data*, not the controller. 
1. Have a model for displaying your collection view cell data
2. confirm them from your tableview cell itself!

```
extension yourTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    // Respective methods
}

extension yourTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    // Respective methods
}
```

Comment: You are right, but from the Model perspective. But what about a controller. Cells are subclasses of `UIView`, so they are basically just views. By conforming to the data source, we say that table view cells should provide data to collection view cells. But that is the responsibility of controllers, which connect views and models with each other by providing data to views

Comment: you have confused the view in MVC with UIView. 
A view object is an object in an application that users can see. A view object 'knows how to draw itself' and can 'respond to user actions'
Refer - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html

Comment: Yes, and `UIView` conforms to the definition of a view object, doesn't it?